# Client can't write into an external server's nodes

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I've tried to write both a String and LocalizedText (the two main data types used in the server), I get no error but when I read the node again one second after the call nothing has changed (and I don't see the new values when using an OPC Inspector either)
My writeOpcValue function is very simple and based on the functions that were provided with milo:

```
/*Writes a String to the nodeId given as parameter*/
public void writeOpcValue(OpcUaClient client, NodeId nodeId, String value, boolean logValue)
{        
    //client.writeValue(nodeId, DataValue.valueOnly(new Variant(value)));
    VariableNode node = client.getAddressSpace().createVariableNode(nodeId);
    node.writeValue(DataValue.valueOnly(new Variant(value)));
    if (logValue)
        logger.info("Wrote {} to nodeId {}", value, nodeId);
}
```

The first line is commented out because I tried both ways, but nothing changed. When I use this function with my own sample server it works perfectly fine but on the "real" one it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong or is there something that should be done server-side? It should be noted that I have no access to the server's code or namespace, and it is in fact not even written in Java, which hasn't caused any issue so far.
Maybe those nodes are Read-Only? In that case I would expect to see an exception or error somewhere though.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

You should at the very least check to see if the StatusCode returned by the `writeValue` call tells you anything useful instead of ignoring it.

Comment: You're right, I definitely should have checked that before asking the question. Now I did and I get `StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}` as a result for two of my three calls, with the last one returning Bad_NotWritable instead (which makes sense, I realized that the Inspector shows that node's access as CurrentRead). But there's still no change in the tree for the two calls that return a Good status either.

Comment: In that case you have a problem to investigate with the Server. If it returns StatusCode Good in response to your Write then you've done all you can do on the Client side.